# iOS Crash if the orientation changes while view is changing

Tags: ios, objective-c, view, crash, orientation

I am having a bug where if the orientation of the device changes while the view is changing the view will lose all of its subviews and if any action is taken the app will crash.

I tried turning off listening for orientation changes if viewWillDissappear but this still doesn't solve the problem. Has anyone else had this problem? And how can I fix it?

EDIT: the exception I am getting is "Can't add self as subview"

Here is how I push a new view controller

ClassA.h

```
@class ClassB;
@interface ClassA : UIViewController {

ClassB *classb;
}
```

ClassA.m

```
-(void)buttonAction:(UIButton*)sender{

    classb = [[[ClassB alloc] initWithNibName:@"myNibName" bundle:nil ClassA:self] autorelease];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:classb animated:YES];
}
```

ClassB.m

```
//turn on orientation
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self  selector:@selector(orientationChanged:)  name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification  object:nil];
}

//turn off orientation
-(void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]removeObserver:self name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification object:nil];
}
```

EDIT2: I believe it is a problem with how I detect orientation and change the view. I will work on rebuilding that code/getting apples standard orientation code working. Thank you for your help.

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: could you add some codes ?

Comment: Add an exception breakpoint. When you hit the exception breakpoint click continue a couple of times and you will get a backtrace and more error info. Post that if you still can't figure out what is happening. Also, post an exact copy of messages.

Comment: ...and post crash dumps / stack traces you're getting, please.

Comment: Might try `viewWillDisappear` instead of `viewDidDisappear`. BTW, the Debugger is your friend waiting to help, it want's to tell you the line that caused the crash. It is feeling dejected and ignored.